# How to Sort Array in Double List Ansible?

Tags: json, ansible

I have a double list like this:

```
dataset:
    - [dataone, A]
    - [datatwo, C]
    - [dataa, B]
    - [dataa, C]
    - [dataa, B]
```

I want to sort the first array and have the second array stick with the first one like this:

```
data:
    - [dataa, B]
    - [dataa, C]
    - [dataa, B]
    - [dataone, A]
    - [datatwo, C]
```

Any duplicate data needs to still show (the arrangement of second array value doesnt matter)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
- set_fact:
    data: "{{ dataset | sort | list }}"

- name: returned data
  debug:         
    var: data
```